# How does Ubuntu define which linux-headers-* will be installed alongside linux-headers-generic?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, linux-headers, 23.04

While upgrading from 22.10 to 23.04, I ran into [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2017267?comments=all) which made the system unbootable because the newest kernel `6.2.0-20` has not been installed correctly.

I used the GRUB startup menu to define an older kernel (apparently, `5.19.0-41` is the only one available "behind" the newest `6.2.0-20`), so now I run on this older kernel.

To cleanup my system I tried to `apt remove linux-headers-6.2.0-20` and all other `6.2.0-20`-related headers of the new and broken kernel, but this was not possible because the unspecific `linux-headers-generic` depended on those packages.

So I also removed `linux-headers-generic` with the plan to re-install it once I removed the problematic headers. I manually purged all of those new headers until the list was pretty much empty (I left `linux-libc-dev:amd64` because it seemed this was not causing problems):

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep "6.2.0-20"
pi  linux-headers-6.2.0-20                                      6.2.0-20.20                               all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.2.0
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic                                6.2.0-20.20                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                                        6.2.0-20.20                               amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
rc  linux-modules-6.2.0-20-generic                              6.2.0-20.20                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-20-generic                        6.2.0-20.20                               amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

But now, when `apt install linux-headers-generic` it will still try to install the newest headers alongside it:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-generic
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden installiert:
  linux-headers-6.2.0-20 linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic
```

Now I wonder, how does the system determine that it will install a newer kernel when installing the general `linux-headers-generic` and can I somehow reset this to the older kernel?

Comment: btw: When doing this I also removed `pfring-dkms` because it was a dependency. Now, when trying to install it again, the package is not found. After a reboot, my virtual machine has the second monitor black and the mouse click is not working, although the mouse cursor is generally visible and movable. I also removed `libc6-dev`.

Answer (score 5):

`5.19.0-41` was an Ubuntu 22.10 kernel. It's not in the repository for 23.04, so you won't find it with `apt`. It was probably still on your system from before you upgraded.

`linux-headers-generic` is a metapackage, which always points to the latest set of headers.

You can specify exactly what headers to install by `apt install linux-headers-6.2.0-20-generic` for example, which the metapackage points to (see [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-meta_6.2.0.20.20/changelog))

However you won't be able to `apt install` the `linux-headers-5.19.0-41-generic` because, as mentioned above, it's not in the 23.04 repo.

You could, as you're running 5.19 on 23.04, go and get the deb manually:

- Start here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/5.19.0-40.41
- Click the `amd64` link which gets you to: [this page](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/25692576)
- Then scroll down to get: [linux-headers-5.19.0-40-generic_5.19.0-40.41_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/25692576/+files/linux-headers-5.19.0-40-generic_5.19.0-40.41_amd64.deb) and [linux-headers-5.19.0-40_5.19.0-40.41_all.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/25692576/+files/linux-headers-5.19.0-40_5.19.0-40.41_all.deb)
- Put those two debs in a folder then use: `sudo apt install ./*.deb`, and you should be set.

Comment: This is a nice answer, however this will not install `linux-headers-generic`. Also, I had to first install the `...all.deb` since the other package depends on it.

Comment: I did more digging and I wonder why `linux-headers-generic` (without additional specification at the end of the name) is not availlabe here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/kernel/ Should it not be?

Comment: Yes, that's the previous release, which points to the kernel headers I mentioned. You certainly can install that along with the versioned headers I mentioned.

Comment: I can find the kernel headers and installed them. But the problem is, that the metapackage `linux-headers-generic` (and also the more meta `linux-generic`) is not installed automatically along with the kernel headers. So I tried to find this package, but it is not in the list. I suspect now, as a metapackage, it is never "downloadable", but created in some process, see bottom: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages. I also suspect I will get problems without those packages when trying to upgrade from 23.04 later on. So, I have to create them. But I am not sure how.

Comment: More precisely: I can do `dpkg -i linux-generic_5.19.0.41.37_amd64.deb` but it will complain, that `linux-headers-generic` is missing and a dependency. But there is no package `linux-headers-generic__5.19.0.41.37_amd64.deb` I can download (or any package with the name `linux-headers-generic`).

Comment: If you just install the `linux-headers-generic` from your current release, it will pull in the 6.2.20 headers, which will fulfil the requirements?

Comment: But this was what I wanted to avoid, because the new kernel was broken. But I am fine now, I was able to install the new kernel by downloading it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2017267?comments=all

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *don't* want to install linux-headers-generic, since that package depends on other packages which are causing problems for you.

There are two ways to handle this:

1. Find the latest version of linux-headers-generic that works for you, and install it. Then, place a hold on that package so that it won't upgrade automatically. Then, once, the latest headers include a fix for the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2017267?comments=all) you mentioned, release the hold and upgrade to the latest version.

   This strategy is a lot of work, since you have to hunt down a working version, test and make sure it works, then clean up each version that doesn't work. Finally, if the latest working version is not available to your current version of Ubuntu, it's extra work to add the package, as [popey's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1465386) intimates.
2. Leave your system as is, in a working state. Don't make any changes until the bug gets fixed, at which time, you'll be able to install the latest version of linux-headers-generic in exactly the normal way that you install other software.

   If this strategy doesn't work for you, why not? Why is it so important to install this package?

Comment: Thanks! I am not able to install an old version of `linux-headers-generic`. So, this option is not possible. But as I mentioned in my comments on the other answer, I was able to install the kernel (and all the headers) by downloading it.